# SDL2 only seems to poll input every 50ms

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

I have noticed that SDL2 only seems to poll input at roughly 50ms.

For example if I poll events like this is my mainloop

```
SDL_Event event;
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
    if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN || event.type == SDL_KEYUP){
         inputs.push_back(...);
    }
}
```

that the input vector is actually empty, for some frames. Only when I use `SDL_Delay(50)` in my mainloop I can avoid getting an empty input vector.

Can I force SDL2 to update the input faster than 50ms?

Comment: There is actual polling?  Seems a bit strange on most OS...

Comment: @MartinJames I am not sure what your are trying to say. Are you saying that the `50ms` is how often my OS polls the input? `50ms` seems quite huge though.  At 60fps I would only get new inputs every 3 frames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing at all to do with SDL.  SDL is a wrapper around functions like [PeekMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943(v=vs.85).aspx), and SDL can't return events with more resolution than these underlying platform-specific functions.  The actual hardware polling rate will be managed by the OS, and is often under 10ms, sometimes as low as 1ms.

The name can be somewhat misleading, since `SDL_PollEvent` does not actually poll hardware. Instead the hardware polling happens continuously in the background as a normal part of your operating system's functionality. `SDL_PumpEvents` moves events from the OS event queue to the SDL event queue.  `SDL_PollEvent` moves an event from the SDL event queue to your own application.  So think of `SDL_PollEvent` as polling an OS queue rather than polling your actual hardware.

It looks like the problem here is a misunderstanding.  The `SDL_KEYDOWN` event does not mean that the key *is* down, it means that the key *became* down or is "repeating".  The repeat rate is configurable your OS's control panel.  So if I press a key, hold it, and then release it, I will get a series of events like this:

```
SDL_KEYDOWN  pressed the key
SDL_KEYDOWN  repeat #1, after the repeat delay
SDL_KEYDOWN  repeat #2, quickly afterwards
SDL_KEYDOWN  repeat #3, quickly
...          ...
SDL_KEYUP    released the key
```

You'll want something like this:

```
switch (event.type) {
case SDL_KEYDOWN:
    key_pressed = true;
    break;
case SDL_KEYUP:
    key_pressed = false;
    break;
}
```

Or you can use [SDL_GetKeyboardState](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState) instead.